# External hyperlinks to control Openlayers map

Tags: openlayers-2, geoext

I have a basic map defined like show below (pseudo code).

After the map.addLayers call there is a displayData(theid) which I want to call from the main body of the html document, the problem is I can't call the method.  I can achieve what I am after if I bind an onclick event to the id of the <a> tag but there's going to be too many links to bind to each and every <a> tag

Clicking on one of the hyperlinks below results in no method displayData() defined.

Thanks for reading!

```
<script>
    Ext.onReady(function() {
    map = new OpenLayers.Map();
    basemap = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(...);
    mylines = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(...);
    selected_items = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(...);
    map.addLayers([basemap, mylines, selected_items]);

    //attach an onclick even for the button on the search results page
    function displayData(theid) {
        //display map window if it is not visible
        OpenLayers.Request.GET({
            url: 'http://1.1.1.1:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&featureId='+theid,
            proxy: "../gis/geoserver.seam?url=",
            success: function(response) {
            //if were successful then add the returned features to the map and zoom to the extent
            var gmlReader = new OpenLayers.Format.GML({ extractAttributes: true });
            selected_items.removeAllFeatures();
            selected_items.addFeatures(gmlReader.read(response.responseText));
            map.zoomToExtent(selected_items.getDataExtent());
        }
    });
}

</script>

<body>
    <div id="map" class="smallmap"></div>

    <br/><a href="" onlick="displayData('feature1');">View on map</a>
    <br/><a href="" onlick="displayData('feature2');">View on map</a>
    <br/><a href="" onlick="displayData('feature3');">View on map</a>
    <br/><a href="" onlick="displayData('feature4');">View on map</a>

</body>
```

Comment: I think problem more about the scope of the function it would be good to define this function outside main Ext.onReady(function) { } block.

Comment: Please check out http://gis.ibbeck.de/ginfo/apps/OLExamples/OL26/examples/styles_unique_with_group_opener.html

Answer (score 1):

I have made some changes in the code can you try. I hope it will help.

```
    <script>

    var map;
    var basemap;
    var mylines;
    var selected_items;

        Ext.onReady(function() {
        map = new OpenLayers.Map();
        basemap = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(...);
        mylines = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(...);
        selected_items = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(...);
        map.addLayers([basemap, mylines, selected_items]);


    });

//attach an onclick even for the button on the search results page
        function displayData(theid) {
            //display map window if it is not visible
            OpenLayers.Request.GET({
                url: 'http://1.1.1.1:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&featureId='+theid,
                proxy: "../gis/geoserver.seam?url=",
                success: function(response) {
                //if were successful then add the returned features to the map and zoom to the extent
                var gmlReader = new OpenLayers.Format.GML({ extractAttributes: true });
                selected_items.removeAllFeatures();
                selected_items.addFeatures(gmlReader.read(response.responseText));
                map.zoomToExtent(selected_items.getDataExtent());
            }
        });
    }
    </script>

    <body>
        <div id="map" class="smallmap"></div>

        <br/><a href="" onlick="displayData('feature1');">View on map</a>
        <br/><a href="" onlick="displayData('feature2');">View on map</a>
        <br/><a href="" onlick="displayData('feature3');">View on map</a>
        <br/><a href="" onlick="displayData('feature4');">View on map</a>

    </body>
```

Comment: Opps, there's no changes between your code and mine!

Comment: Have you tried? In your code function was in onReady Block whereas in mine it is defined outside ready block. Give it a try and see if it works.

Comment: Please check out http://gis.ibbeck.de/ginfo/apps/OLExamples/OL26/examples/styles_unique_with_group_opener.html and also http://gis.ibbeck.de/ginfo/apps/OLExamples/OL29/WFS_with_multiple_featureTypes.asp